# Issue with timer Input Capture mode in STM32

Tags: c, timer, stm32, hal

I would like to trigger a timer with an external signal which happens every 1ms. Then, the timer has to count up to 90us at every rising edge of the external signal. The question is, can I do that using a general purpose timer configured as Input Compare? I don’t understand which callBack to use for this purpose.

I’m using the HAL library and TIM2 peripheral in STM32F446 microcotnroller.

This is how I configured my timer peripheral

```
void TIMER2_Config(void)
{
TIM_IC_InitTypeDef timer2IC_Config;
htimer2.Instance = TIM2;
htimer2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
htimer2.Init.Period = 89; //Fck=50MHz, Timer period = 90us

htimer2.Init.Prescaler = 49;
if ( HAL_TIM_IC_Init(&htimer2) != OK)
   Error_handler();
timer2IC_Config.ICPolarity = TIM_ICPOLARITY_RISING; 
timer2IC_Config.ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htimer2, &timer2IC_Config, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != OK)
  Error_handler();

}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to say which part you are using.  For example, on STM32F401 you can do this with general purpose timers TIM2-TIM5 but not with general purpose timers TIM9-TIM11.

Comment: @TomV , done. I'm using TIM2 and STM32F446. I would like to activate an ADC in the timer callback, so I need to know a way to do this usign input capture of the timer.

Comment: Please add new information to your question by [edit]ing it, do _not_ post a comment, as it is not a comment. Additionally you have now different statements. What do you want, delay for 90µs or trigger an ADC? What have you tried? Please show a [mre]. In what way does it not work for you?

Comment: Please confirm or correct (in your question): You want an external trigger signal (rising edge) to start a timer, which after 90µs starts a conversion of an ADC. And the issue is that you don't know how to set up the timer... What _did_ you try? Did you implement the start of the timer by the external signal? Did you implement the start of the ADC's conversion? Did you read the documentation, and why did it not help you?

Comment: @thebusybee, yes, what you said is correct. I tried using the timer in Input Capture mode, configured as I posted above. I wrote the code to set a port as an alternate function to act as an input channel for that timer. I used the callBack function HAL_PeriodElapsedCallBack, to start the ADC in interrupt mode. The code does not work correctly, the timer does not start counting on any rising edge, but counts periodically.

Comment: Hm, Input Capture mode does not seem right, as you don't want to _capture_ the counter value on the trigger, but to _reset_ the counter. I don't have the device at hand, but please read chapter 17.3.14 and the sub chapter on Reset mode. And chapter 17.3.10 for One-pulse mode. The next step would be to use the Output Compare pulse to trigger the ADC...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is well within the features of this peripheral, but you must remember that the HAL library is not capable of using the full features of the chip.  Sometimes you have to use access the registers directly (the LL library is another way to do this).

To have the external signal start the timer you need to use trigger mode, not input capture.  Input capture means record the value of the timer which is already started.  You need to set the field TIMx_CCMRx_CCxS to 0b11 (3) to make the input a trigger, then set the field TIMx_SMCR_TS to select the channel you are using, and TIMx_SMCR_SMS to 0b110 (6) to select start on trigger mode.

Next set up the prescaler and reload register to to count for the 90 microsecond delay that you want, and set TIMx_CR1_OPM to 1 to stop the counter wrapping when it reaches the limit.

Next set TIMx_CR2_MMS to 0b010 to output a trigger on the update event.

Finally you can set the ADCx_CR2_EXTSEL bits to 0b00110 to trigger on TIM2_TRGO trigger output.

This is all a bit complicated, but the reference manual is very thorough and you should read the whole chapter through and check every field in the register description section.  I would recommend not mixing the HAL library with direct register access, it will probably interfere with what you are trying to do.